# How to get the second animation to start, only after the first animation has finished using Javascript callbacks?

Tags: javascript, animation

I have two animations which both work, but I'd like to have it so the second animation starts only after the first animation has finished, I tried this with Javascript callbacks but can't seem to get it to work. I'm sure someone can show me how to do this. There must be other ways to do this too? I'd be really interested to find out what they are actually. It's amazing how many different ways there are too do things isn't it.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", first, false);
var obj, height, goUp;

function first() {
  obj = document.getElementById("thetext");
  obj.style.position = "absolute";
  obj.style.bottom = "10px";
  height = document.body.clientHeight;
  
  goUp = true
  second();
}

function second() {
  var pos = parseInt(obj.style.bottom, 10);
  
  (goUp) ? pos++ : pos--;
  obj.style.bottom = pos + "px";
  
  if (pos < 0) {
    goUp = true;
  }
  if (pos > height) {
    goUp = false;
  }
  if (pos < 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  setTimeout(second, 10);
}

var objz, width, goRight;

function animatefirst() {
  objz = document.getElementById("tues");
  objz.style.position = "absolute";
  objz.style.left = "10px";
  objz.style.bottom = "10px";
  width = document.body.clientWidth;

  goRight = true;
  animatesecond();
}

function animatesecond() {
  var position = parseInt(objz.style.left, 10);

  (goRight) ? position++ : position--;
  objz.style.left = position + "px";

  if (position > width) {
    goRight = false;
  }
  if (position < 0) {
    goRight = true;
  }
  if (position < 0) {
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(animatesecond, 10);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="thetext">ANIMATION </p>
  <p id="tues"> Tuesday</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You should use either css animations, classes and `transitionend` events, **or** the JS Web Animation API and a Promise chain.

Comment: Sheraff, the thing is, I don't want to use css or the JS Web Animation API, I want to do it in vanilla Javascript as a learning exercise.

Comment: the web animation api is vanilla JS. If you don't want to use it, you'll have to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`, preferably animate `transform` instead of `left` and deal with callbacks or learn about `Promise`

Comment: The web animation api is vanilla JS, but it's a built in method, I am looking to program the function myself, I will try your other ideas thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in a simple way, I just put my call to the next function just before the return; which closes the current function. So the call to the next function is not inserted until the part in the code where the first function has finished, to avoid overlapping functions. I'm surprised no one could help with this, but it must be a very busy site :)

```
 if (pos < 0) {
 nextfunction();
 return;
 }
```